# How to allow user to copy my email address but not crawlers?

Tags: html, css, web-crawler

I have an issue that some crawlers that crawl the email address from my website and send spam emails.

Is there a way that allows the normal user to copy the email but not crawlers(That can't detect `xxx@xxx.com` format in the html source code)?

I tried the following solution, but none of them works while copying the email address:

#### Solution 1

> Try copying this will not copy `@` and `.com`

```css
.name::after {
  content: '@';
}

.mail::after {
  content: '.com';
}
```

```html
<span class="name">foo</span><span class="mail">gmail</span>
```

#### Solution 2

> Try copying this makes `foo` and `@gmail.com` reversed.

```css
.mail {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<div class="mail">
  <span>@gmail.com</span>
  <span>foo</span>
</div>
```

Comment: how about make a bottom for copy ?

Comment: I've thought fo that, but I need to show the email address list according to the design. Just trying to find if there's a workaround to avoid using javascript and generating an image of email, that's kinda dumb :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding an HTML comment between the email.

```html
<div class="mail">
  <span>foo<!--not an email-->@gmail.com</span>
</div>
```

However, as the OP mentioned, crawlers can easily filter HMTL comments. If you run your raw code through minifyers too, comments can be filtered out.

You can also try injecting your email into DOM with Javascript.

```html
<div id="mail"></div>
<script>
  document.querySelector("#mail").innerText = ["foo", "gmail.com"].join("@")
</script>
```

This makes it impossible for crawlers that don't run Javascript to see your email. To make it more usable for your users though, you can also implement [copy-on-click](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp).

```html
<input type="text" readonly id="mail">
<script>
  let email = ["foo", "gmail.com"].join("@")
  let element = document.querySelector("#mail")
  element.value = email
  element.addEventListener('click', e => {
    element.select()
    element.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
    document.execCommand("copy")
  })
</script>
<style>
   #mail{
     appearance: none; 
     border: 0; 
     outline: 0;
     font-family: inherit;
     font-size: inherit;
   }
</style>
```

The input can be styled to act like normal inline-block text. You can add a momentary tooltip that appears once copied.

Comment: Thanks! The first solution might work, but some crawler might filter out comments, maybe something like `<span>foo<span style="display: none;">hello</span>@gmail.com</span>` could work!

Comment: Right, I wanted to mention that. Minify tools will remove comments too unless specified not to. Will add a note.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the user to click a button to have JavaScript copy the email for them.

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick = () => {

  const span = document.querySelector('span');
  const before = window.getComputedStyle(span, ':before').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/"/g, '');
  const after = window.getComputedStyle(span, ':after').getPropertyValue('content').replace(/"/g, '');

  const input = document.createElement('input');
  document.body.append(input);
  input.value = before + after;
  input.select();
  input.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
  document.execCommand('copy');
  input.remove();
}
```

```css
span:before {
  content: 'foo';
}

span:after {
  content: '@bar.com';
}
```

```html
<span></span><button>Copy!</button>
```

Comment: That's basically what Craigslist does to protect user's phone numbers. Good strategy.